# Anagram consecutive letters probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Say I have a word like **resemblance** with 11 letters and 3 e letters.
I know there are 11!/3!=6652800 anagrams for the word. (Not real words obviously.)

My question is what is the probability within those permutations that all three e letters are next to one another? Thanks.

Comment: Edit: I'm not specifically asking for a solution but formulas to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: treat the three adjacent "e"s as a single letter so that you effectively have 9 letters. This will allow you to count the number of words such that the three "e"s are together, and you can then divide by $11!/3!$ to obtain the probability.

Comment: Hey, thanks. So would I do 3! divided by 11!/3!? Since e's can be ordered in 3! ways